# Remove specific character if at the beginning of a string or consecutive at any place in a string

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to make a regex to remove every of those character [0-9] \ - * \' if they are either at the beginning of the string, end of the string or if they are consecutive in a string.

I currently have this regex /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ *'-][a-zA-Z]+)*$/gm but it only tells me if it matches the absence of specific character at the beginning of a string, end of a string or consecutive character, but I'm not sure how I should remove the non-matching characters since it contains multiple regex class (I don't think I can only use ^ and makes it work)

I've made unit tests over here 
https://regex101.com/r/wNxttF/2

- "This is --- not correct because it contains 5 consecutives non-letters characters" Should return "This is not correct because it contains 5 consecutives non-letters characters"
- "This         " Should return "This"
- "         This" Should return "This"
- "1234567890" Should return ""

Comment: Perhaps you could match them using an alternation `^[ *'0-9-]+|[ *'0-9-]+$|[ *'0-9-]{2,}`  See https://regex101.com/r/wNxttF/4

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but is there some way to also remove every non-characters ( ?&_$) ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$|[^a-zA-Z]{2,}` https://regex101.com/r/xkKlvo/1

Comment: Try `^[-\s*']+|[-\s*']+$|(?:[^-\s*'a-zA-Z]|([-\s*']))+` and replace with `$1`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZHZWY/2).

Comment: See [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183654/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an alternation and a character class listing all the characters that you want to remove at the start of the string, the end or repeated 2 or more times using `{2,}`

```
^[ *'0-9?&_$-]+|[ *'0-9?&_$-]+$|[ *'0-9?&_$-]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xSbzeW/1)

If you want to remove all except characters a-zA-Z and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match any character not in the character class

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$|[^a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkKlvo/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I currently changed your regex to match my needs : ^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$|[\ \-\'\*]{2,}, now it removes everything non-characters at the begining and at the end. It also remove specific character if they are consecutive -*'. The only thing missing is to remove every other chacter like ?&() if they are present, while keeping -*' if they are non consecutive.

Comment: @J.Lev You could add them to a character class as well https://regex101.com/r/9dBCj6/1 There is also an option using a capturing group and repeating the backreference to keep consecutive matches https://regex101.com/r/9dBCj6/2

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$|(['* -])['* -]+|[^a-zA-Z'* -]
```

Replace with the backreference to Group 1 value, `$1`:

```
s.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$|(['* -])['* -]+|[^a-zA-Z'* -]/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e9ZrH9/1)

**Details**

- `^[^a-zA-Z]+` - one or more chars other than ASCII letters at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z]+$` - one or more chars other than ASCII letters at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `(['* -])['* -]+` - a `'`, `*`, space or `-` captured into Group 1 and then 1+ or more of such chars
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z'* -]` - a char other than ASCII letter, `'`, `*`, space or `-`.

Comment: @SeaSharp It matches what it should.

Comment: It has to be consecutive (means: at least 2).

Comment: Why? this ragex will remove ALL the spaces. it will concatenate all the words together.

Comment: @SeaSharp And did you see the result?

Comment: Yes. I think we are not talking about the same Demo - link...?

Comment: @SeaSharp You must be talking about Thefourthbird's https://regex101.com/r/xkKlvo/1/.